# Beamer and translator package

Tags: beamer, dictionaries, translator

I created slides using beamer and everything was working fine. Now, I wanted to run the same file on a different computer but I get the following error from the beamerbasetranslator.sty file: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.\usedictionary

I include a minimal working example here even I believe the code is fine

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}  %% Themenwahl

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I guess there is a more general problem with the latex installation? I checked the installed package, the usepackage translator is installed but just when I tried to compile, so was never used before. Any ideas what went wrong?
I don't think that I will need the translator package but it seems automatically included in beamer? Can I somehow avoid it?

Comment: Are larex on both pcs fully up to date?

Comment: Your MWE just runs fine on my computer.